# Passing an array back to a main method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, pass-by-reference

Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int [] array = new int [1000];
    int[] getArray=FileArrayProvider(array);

    for (int y = 0; y < getArray.length; ++y)
        {
        System.out.print(array[y] + " ");
        }
```

I want to pass 'array' into the method 'FileArrayProvider below:

```
    public static int[] FileArrayProvider(int[] array1) throws IOException{
    File file = new File("RandomNumbers.txt");
    FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

    {String s =in.readLine();
    System.out.println("Array before sorting: ");
    while(s!=null)
    {int k = 0;
    array1[k] = Integer.parseInt(s); 
    System.out.print(array1[k]+" ");
    s = in.readLine();
}

        in.close();
        }
    return array1;
    }
```

The problem is that the array is not being passed back to the main method. It is printing properly within the 'FileArrayprovider' method but is passing only the last value of the array back to the main method and is filling the array with all zeros apart from that. Any tips or advice would be much appreciated to fix this!Thanks

Comment: There is no point to returning `array1` since it's the same as the argument, and you never assign to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that in your `FileArrayProvider()` method the int `k` is never incremented your essentially only changing the first value of `array1`. Change it to this and see if that works.

```
String s =in.readLine();
System.out.println("Array before sorting: ");
int k = 0;
while(s!=null)
{
    array1[k] = Integer.parseInt(s); 
    System.out.print(array1[k]+" ");
    s = in.readLine();
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because inside for loop where you are printing array in the main()

`System.out.print(array[y] + " ");`

you are printing `array[y]` and not printing new value which is 
 `getArray`

Comment: thanks for your answer but that still doesn't solve it. the array is printing correctly in the FileArrayProvider method but it still only takes the last value from the array when i pass it back to main() and populates the rest of the array with zeros.